# Recursive components data reference problem

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build a category selector component which gets a tree of categories as input in first hand as follows:

```
 mockData: Category[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'main cat1', children: [
       { id: 3, name: 'sub cat1', children: []},
       { id: 4, name: 'sub kat2', children: []}
    ]},
    { id: 2, name: 'main cat2', children: [
      { id: 5, name: 'sub cat5', children: []},
    ]},
  ]
```

Template:
The component displays the main categories in a `ngFor`. If a category is selected it manually inserts the #tpl marked template into #vc view container. This was a try to my assumption that this would solve the problem.

```
<mat-chip-list aria-label="Category selection" [multiple]="false">
    <mat-chip *ngFor="let chip of data"
              [selected]="chip.id === selectedCategory?.id"
              (click)="clickChip($event, chip)">{{ chip.name }}</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
<ng-container #vc></ng-container>


<ng-template #tpl>
  <span class="divider"> / </span>
  <category [data]="copyOFChildren"
            (selected)="emitSelected($event)"
  ></category>
</ng-template>
```

The component:

```
export class CategorySelectorComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

  @Input() data: Category[];
  @Output() selected: EventEmitter<Category> = new EventEmitter();

  selectedCategory: Category;
  copyOFChildren: Category[];

  @ViewChild("vc", {read: ViewContainerRef, static: true}) vc: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('tpl', {static:true}) tpl: TemplateRef<any>;
  childViewRef: ViewRef;

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.childViewRef = this.tpl.createEmbeddedView(null);
  }

  clickChip(event, category) {
    this.removeChildView();

    this.selectedCategory = (this.selectedCategory && this.selectedCategory.id === category.id) ? null : {...category};
    this.selected.emit(this.selectedCategory);
    this.insertChildView();
  }

  emitSelected(category: Category | null):void {
    if (category) {
      this.selected.emit(category)
    } else {
      this.selected.emit(this.selectedCategory)
    }
  }

  insertChildView(){
    if (this.selectedCategory && this.selectedCategory.children.length) {
      this.copyOFChildren = [ ...this.selectedCategory.children ];
      this.vc.insert(this.childViewRef);
    }
  }

  removeChildView(){
    this.copyOFChildren = undefined;
    this.vc.detach();
    console.log('detach')
  }
}
```

The problem occurs when I do the following:

1. select 'main cat1' then select it's sub category (sub cat 1)
2. select the other main category 'main cat2' then switch back to 'main cat1'
3. Result: 'main cat1' is highlighted but previously selected (step 1.) 'sub cat1' is highlighted as well

The output is correct, the log says that 'main cat1' is selected

So, the problem is that 'sub cat1' chip remains highlighted as it was selected as well.
Only 'main cat1' should be highlighted.

Seems the inserted component holds it's data somehow.
I couldn't figure it out how.

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/category-selector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile a solution was found.

The problem was that I kept the recursive element's component alive so it kept in memory because it was present in the template as this:

```
<ng-template #tpl>
  <span class="divider"> / </span>
  <category [data]="copyOFChildren"
            (selected)="emitSelected($event)"
  ></category>
</ng-template>
```

Solution:
Instead of using `<ng-template>` I used the `ComponentFactoryResolver` to manually create the child component and bind inputs & outputs to it.

Check the demo: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/category-selector-fcucy6)